# In what order are the rules handled in the Linux Firewall Module in webmin?

Tags: iptables, firewall, webmin

If I'm not mistaken it's top to bottom correct?  And the catch-all default action at the end is to just drop any packets that don't match the rules above.  Should I be logging the dropped packets as well as the last rule if this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

> If I'm not mistaken it's top to bottom correct?

Yes, correct

> And the catch-all default action at the end is to just drop any packets that don't match the rules above?

Possibly, but don't count on it. the default action for a given chain is determined by the policy for that Chain.

You can check the current policy with

```
[sudo] iptables -S
```

you will see something like (in this case the policy for input chain = drop)

```
-P INPUT DROP
```

and you can set the policy (if its currently something different) with

```
[sudo] iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

> Should I be logging the dropped packets as well as the last rule if this is the case?

Up to you. Many people do, just make a rule like this

```
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

And position it at the bottom of your ruleset - so its the last thing to match the packet before it gets `DROP`ed by the chain policy.
By default the log messages will be sent to the same log file as the kernel, but `rsyslog` allows you to define your own custom  file for firewall logs

Comment: The logging rule is really helpful. Thanks a lot!